# Why method setColumnFilterCriteria() gives 'Cannot call method "setColumnFilterCriteria" of null'?

Tags: google-apps-script

Problem seems to be very easy to solve, but I've spent a lot of time finding the answer and I'm going crazy...

I use very simple code to add the filetering to the sheet and I keep getting the same error:

TypeError: Cannot call method "setColumnFilterCriteria" of null.

The range starts from row 5. In column 50 I have different letters, including "r". I've also tried with the numbers.

Sorry if the case is too easy, but I think that I won't solve it on my own...

Script:

```
function filtering() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//remove filter and flush
if(sheet.getFilter() != null){sheet.getFilter().remove();}
SpreadsheetApp.flush();

var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberGreaterThan(10).build();  
// I've also tried commented lines
// var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains("r").build();  
// var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualTo('r').build();  
// var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(["r"]).build();  
// var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setVisibleValues(["r"]).build();

sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(50, criteria);

//also I've tried with the range
/*
var range = sheet.getRange(5, 1, 100, 50);
range.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(50, criteria);
*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue is in this line

```
if(sheet.getFilter() != null) {
     sheet.getFilter().remove();
}
```

If there exists any filter, we clearing them. Then we're doing

```
sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(50, criteria);
```

Here `getFilter()` will always return `null`, as we have cleared the filter in previous step.

We can fix this by clearing existing filter and creating new filter.

Something like this:

```
if(sheet.getFilter() != null) {
     sheet.getFilter().remove();
}
sheet.getDataRange().createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(50, criteria);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have a filter on the sheet. The problem is in sheet.getFilter(), but not in your criteria.
According to the documentation:

> getFilter() Returns the filter in this sheet, or null if there is no filter.