# Current Value Filter in Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Similar to the question here 
[ExcelVBA_CurrentValuecu_Filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198945/excelvba-currentvaluecu-filter)

```
I want

(1,A)=data

(2,A)=a

(3,A)=b

(4,A)=c

(5,A)=b

(6,A)=d


CurrentCell(3,A) ---> execute --> output (2,A)=b,(3,A)=b
```

```
function Spreadsheet_CurrentValue_Filter() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-4, 0).activate();

  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
                               .setHiddenValues(['', 'a', 'c', 'd'])
                               .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter()
                              .setColumnFilterCriteria(spreadsheet
                                                       .getActiveRange()
                                                       .getColumn(), criteria);
}
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for the bad English!

add----------------------------------

(1)myhiddendata=['', 'a', 'c', 'd']

array variable? how to output?

(2)offset(-4, 0).  -4?

Comment: I push Approve. thank you.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want. Either share your spreadsheet as suggested by player0 or try to explain in other words what your filter is supposed to do.

Comment: So, do you want to hide all rows where the entry in column `spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn()` is either '', 'a', 'c', or 'd'? Or you want to hide the row which is -4 offset from your current row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Goal:

Hide all other values in the column filter except value in the currently selected cell(Or show only  elements that are equal to the current cell)

#### Flow:

- Get all values in the current column
- Filter out all values that match current cell value  using `Array#reduce`
- Use `.setHiddenValues()` to set the filtered array (`hiddenValues`) as `setVisibleValues` is still not supported.

#### Snippet:

```
function Spreadsheet_CurrentValue_Filter() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
    sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  var currCell = sheet.getCurrentCell(),
    currCellValue = currCell.getValue(),
    currCol = currCell.getColumn(),
    allValues /**all values in current column */ = sheet
      .getRange(1, currCol, sheet.getLastRow(), 1)
      .getValues();

  /*Get hidden values as a 1D array from 2D array allValues*/
  var hiddenValues = allValues.reduce(function(acc, [row]) {
    if (!(row === currCellValue)) {
      acc.push(row);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);

  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .setHiddenValues(hiddenValues)
    .build();
  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(currCol, criteria);
}
```

Comment: sometime --->    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572697/why-method-setcolumnfiltercriteria-gives-cannot-call-method-setcolumnfilterc